# How do I program my alert to disappear after 3 seconds?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have this alert but I have no idea how to program it in such a way that it will automatically disappear after 3 seconds. I am a beginner and I really am struggling with this. I am using reactJS. [Here is the link of what it looks like incase anyone wants to see it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LQTyI.png)

This is my alert

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" id="alertDiv" role="alert" style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first method that you can use is using jQuery:
This will make the alert disappear after 3 seconds. You use the javascript `setInterval` function and make the function run after 3000 milliseconds. Then I run the jQuery `.fadeOut()` to make it disappear.

```js
setInterval(function(){ $(".alert").fadeOut(); }, 3000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div class="alert alert-success" id="alertDiv" role="alert" style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
 </div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

You can also make it happen without jQuery and using Javascript and some css:
This will also use the Javascript `setInterval` function and Javascript `.style` and `.display` methods which will be set to `none`.

```js
const target = document.getElementById("alertDiv");
window.onload = setInterval(() => target.style.opacity = '0', 3000)
```

```css
#alertDiv {
  transition: opacity 1s;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="alert alert-success" id="alertDiv" role="alert" style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
  <button onclick="document.getElementById('alertDiv').style.opacity = '0'" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
  <strong>Success!</strong> You have been signed in successfully!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is an alert message!   
 $(document).ready(function() { // Show the alert $("#myNoti").fadeIn(); // Set a timeout to hide the alert after 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds) setTimeout(function() { $("#myNoti").fadeOut(); }, 3000); });

---

Answer (score 0):

Add `setTimeout()` to your alert. Something like:

```
 <div class="alert alert-success" id="alertDiv" role="alert" style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    setTimeout(() => { alert("Your message"); }, time);
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow. I think what you're after is [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

This example might help you: https://jsfiddle.net/zdb6vego/

```
var milliseconds = 3000;

setTimeout(function () {
    document.getElementById('my-app').remove();
}, milliseconds);
```